# How to use Foreach in JavaScript to do multiplication of 2 multiline textboxes

Tags: javascript

I am learning some new concept in JavaScript.
Can some body help me to achieve the following results.

[image]

Values1(this.getField("Text6")) is a **multiline textbox**

Values2(this.getField("Text7")) is a **multiline textbox**

Result (this.getField("Text8")) is the product of Value 1 and Value2

Tested the following code to display only the Values 2 in Result box by using foreach method.But I am not sure how to perform multiplication within it?

```
var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split('\r');
var values2 = this.getField("Text7").value.split('\r');
this.getField("Text8").value = "";

values2.forEach(element => this.getField("Text8").value +=(element+'\n'));
```

**Current output:**
[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Z28.png):

Comment: Please edit your question to include ALL relevant code (including HTML). Additionally, be sure to show the complete function in question. Your code uses `this`, but `this` only has value when used within a function, which you aren't showing. Also, in HTML there is no "multiline textbox". We have `textarea` elements.

Comment: Sorry ..I am using the multiline in PDF editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getField` is not a native JavaScript function. I'll just define it in the snippet below.

Some remarks:

- `split('\r')` may not be the best way to get the lines, as there might be `\n` characters in there too. I would instead match numbers with a regular expression (`[\d.]+`).
- As this split up produces strings, I would immediately convert them to numbers by applying the `Number` function to them.
- Instead of accumulating the result with `+=`, create an array with the products and then join these into a multi-line text to assign (once) to the field.
- Use the index you can get during the loop, and with that index get the other number to multiply with

```js
var getField = document.getElementById.bind(document);

var collect = id => (this.getField(id).value.match(/[\d.]+/g) || []).map(Number);

var values1 = collect("Text6");
var values2 = collect("Text7");
this.getField("Text8").value = values2.map((element, i) =>  element*values1[i]).join("\n");
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 5em;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<textarea  id=Text6>
1
2
3
4
</textarea>
<textarea  id=Text7>
4
5
6
7
</textarea><textarea  id=Text8></textarea>
```

Comment: Great solution it is working also..Thanks for showing another way of dealing with this.            Can you explain what is this line doing      match(/[\d.]+/g) || []).map(Number)

Comment: The argument given to `match` is a regular expression: `\d` matches a digit, and `[\d.]` matches a digit or a point (so you can also use decimal numbers). The `+` means 1 or more (of those). `/` is the regular expression delimiter. `g` is for global, meaning all matches should be retrieved. `match` returns an array of strings, and with `.map(Number)` we turn that into an array of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the `forEach` callback is the array index. You can use that to index into `values1`, so you can multiply them.

```
values2.forEach((element, index) => 
    this.getField("Text8").value +=(element * values1[index] + '\n'));
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar...I am getting the results in PDF editor and the code is working fine. But when I try to open the PDF in Web I am getting NaN error...Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: You probably have something in the text box that isn't a number. Maybe a blank line.

Comment: I thing the text box is returning string instead of number in this line                                var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split('\r');      but I am not sure how to convert it back to a number

Comment: The multiplication operator will automatically convert it to to a number. You're getting NaN because something can't be converted to a number.

Comment: Maybe you should use `split('\r\n')`